# ngix ubunu не не передает код интрепретатору php7.0-fpm а просто скачивает php код

Tags: ubuntu, yii2, nginx, php-fpm, php7

Конфиг из *sites-avalible*

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; 

    server_name yii2-lessons.local;
    root        /home/stepan/Yii2_GB_course/yii2_lessons/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /home/stepan/Yii2_GB_course/yii2_lessons/log/access.log;
    error_log   /home/stepan/Yii2_GB_course/yii2_lessons/log/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Конфиг /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d

```
[www]


user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data


pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 5

pm.min_spare_servers = 1

pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, устраните ошибки и форматирование в вашем вопросе.

Comment: А в sites-enabled конфиг подключён?

Answer (score 0):

А если так?

```
listen 80 default_server;
#И на всякий случай для IPV6
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

location ~ \.php$ {
    #Попробуйте добавить эти две строчки
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

И проверьте чтоб в php.ini был

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;
```